# How run Symfony commands in background Docker

Tags: symfony, docker, rabbitmq

I need to run rabbitMQ consumers in Background
How run him in Docker Container?

Comment: You can `docker exec...` onto the container and run the command manually, or you could run a separate container to run the consumer process. The latter being my preference.

Comment: Please more information, is it a dockerfile you're writing ? do you want to run this comand in the same container ? etc...

Comment: a docker configuration with one consumer for container? or a script that run a  new background script in a container?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acording to docker philosophy you need to run it in separate container.
You can reuse your code but it should be defenetly separate container/ May be even different from the one you run web.
You can run it manually:
`docker run -v /path/to/app:/container-dir -w /container-dir your-container php bin/console your:command --env prod`

Or you can use docker-compose or any other tool

P.S. Dont forget to specify user. You need to run it by user with same UID you run your web instance to avoid file access issues

Answer (score 1):

Note that it highly depends on what you want to do and your question is unclear about that, but if you want to start the command in the same container and in the same shell, and you are not interested in any output.

Then it's just like any other linux process :

```
command > /dev/null 2>&1 &
```

Where :

- `command` is  the random command you want to run
- `>/dev/null` sends every `stdout` output to blackhole
- `2>&1` make the same for `stderr`
- `&` run in background

Eventualy use `nohup` if you don't want the command to be killed when closing the shell/user logs out...

```
nohup command > /dev/null 2>&1 &
```